# Clustering and Search Optmization use case Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table in MySQL aurora that i need to migrate to Snowflake .
The **size of the table is 6 TB and it has 3 billion rows**.
90% of the time for our application we use query based on `OBJ_ID` which returns 100 to 1000 records.

DDL in Snowflake similar to MySQL

```
create or replace table app_event (
  ID varchar(36)  not null primary key, 
  VERSION number, 
  ACT_TYPE varchar(255),
  EVE_TYPE varchar(255),
  CLI_ID varchar(36),
  DETAILS variant,
  OBJ_TYPE varchar(255),
  DATE_TIME timestamp,
  AAPP_EVENT_TO_UTC_DT timestamp,
  GRO_ID varchar(36),
  OBJECT_NAME varchar(255),
  OBJ_ID varchar(255),
  USER_NAME varchar(255),
  USER_ID varchar(255),
  EVENT_ID varchar(255),
  FINDINGS varchar(255),
  SUMMARY variant
);
```

We are migrating from MySQL to Snowflake because we need to perform analytics and aggregation queries and MySQL is doing good in that so we are thinking to migrate to Snowflake for that purpose.

Its difficult to maintain MySQL a single 6 TB with such a massive growth and that's why with analytics and aggregation we are thinking to extend some use cases to Snowflake.

So the plan is to keep last 2 year data into MySQL and keep full subset of data into Snowflake.

We can do that but for some use cases where we need to export some report for a uses that need complete data and query would be something like

```
select * from table where OBJ_ID ='1234'
```

Now the question is for 6 TB table 3 Billion rows will, Snowflake perform well for such queries? 1 sec - 3 sec latency is fine.

To get this kind of performance what i need to use **clustering** or **search optimization**

I have Chronological UUID in for OBJ_ID columns and there will be millions of distinct OBJ_ID in that table.

Shall i create table cluster by OBJ_ID?

Is there any way we can make Snowflake work faster for this kind of use case?

Can we use hash-code for clustering and create table just a though or NTILE based grouping?

We are planning to do POC with 200 Million data but is that ok or do we need to test with complete data set?

If we use Snowflake for this kind of use case will the cost be more?

**NOTE:It is a single table no relation with any other table**

**Test One :**
We have loaded 150 million rows
Select based on OBJ_ID which returns 400 rows took 3 sec and when we executed same query then it took 200 ms .

It says
Partition total 350
Partition scanned 250

after that we altered table and used cluster by OBJ_ID but result were same .

We dont know if CLUSTER by if working or not but we did not get any performance gain here

Can we make his faster ?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer because there are multiple questions here and some might argue this is all opinionated. That being said, YES, cluster by the key. The real work of the execution of the queries occurs in the Snowflake warehouses, so you'll want to scale your warehouse definition [scale up with the size] appropriately.

Perform faster than MySQL? Very likely. Your POC will do very well.

Cost? Impossible to compare here.

**Caveat**: Snowflake only enforces NULL/NOT NULL constraints! PK and FK constraints might be shown in the DDL, but YOU HAVE TO MANAGE THIS YOURSELF (aka, in your application).

Comment: I have just this table no relation with any other table .I am just worried about the so cluster by obj_id shoudl work even though we have 500 millions distinct Obejct id

Comment: Sure. They work with bigger data than that, so I wouldn't be conerned.